# values inserted as null into database

Tags: php

hi im trying to insert a url and its content into 2 table but i will use an id from a table and insert this id in multiple entries in the second table i hope i succeed to clarify my issue here the probleme that i can view data but i cant insert data in mysql using pdo all i got in mysql is NULL values is my code for more clarification

first my class file is like that Links.php

```
  /**
  * Sets the object's properties using the values in the supplied array
  *
  * @param assoc The property values
  */

  public function __construct1( $data=array() ) {
    if ( isset( $data['listURL'] ) ) $this->listURL = $data['listURL'];
    if ( isset( $data['hostname'] ) ) $this->hstname = $data['hostname'];
  }
  /**
  * Sets the object's properties using the values in the supplied array
  *
  * @param assoc The property values
  */
  public function __construct2( $data=array() ) {    
    if ( isset( $data['stringName'] ) ) $this->stringName = $data['stringName'];
    if ( isset( $data['stringUrl'] ) ) $this->stringUrl = $stringUrl = $data['stringUrl'];
  }

  /**
  * Sets the object's properties using the edit form post values in the supplied array
  *
  * @param assoc The form post values
  */
  public function storeFormValues1 ( $params ) {

    // Store all the parameters
    $this->__construct1( $params );

  }
  /**
  * Sets the object's properties using the edit form post values in the supplied array
  *
  * @param assoc The form post values
  */
  public function storeFormValues2 ( $params ) {

    // Store all the parameters
    $this->__construct2( $params );

  }

public function insertlistFuncClass() {
    $conn = new PDO(DB_NDS, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO lists ( listURL, hostname ) VALUES (:listURL, :hostname)";
    $st  = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $st->bindValue( ":listurl", $this->url, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":hostname", $this->hstname, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->execute();
    $listId = $conn->lastInsertId();
    $conn = null;
}
public function insertStringsFuncClass() {
  $listId = $this->listId;
  $conn    = new PDO(DB_NDS, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO Strngs ( stringName, stringUrl, listId ) VALUES (:stringName, :stringUrl, :listId)";
  $st  = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $st->bindValue( ":stringName", $this->channelName, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $st->bindValue( ":stringUrl", $this->streamUrl, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $st->bindValue( ":listId", $listId, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $st->execute();
  $conn = null;
}
```

for file.php it is like that:

```
require("config.php");
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
function insertlists()
{
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('allow-origin: *');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ACCEPT, CONTENT-TYPE, X-CSRF-TOKEN");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        $url = $_POST['url'];
        print $url . " was successfully submitted ";
        $createdate     = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
        $hstname        = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        $listsInfo  = array();
        $listArr    = array(
            'listURL' => $url,
            'hostname' => $hstname
        );
        $listInfo[] = $playlistArr;
        print_r($playlistArr);
        $mylink = new Lists;
        $mylink->storeFormValues1($_POST);
        $mylink->insertPlaylistFuncClass();
    
}


function insertStrings()
{
    insertlists();
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('allow-origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ACCEPT, CONTENT-TYPE, X-CSRF-TOKEN");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    $m3ufile    = file_get_contents($url);
    $find = ['/((?:https?|rtmp):\/\/(?:\S*?\.\S*?)(?:[\s)\[\]{};"\'<]?(.mp4)|\.\s|$))/', '/((?:https?|rtmp):\/\/(?:\S*?\.\S*?)(?:[\s)\[\]{};"\'<]?(.avi)|\.\s|$))/', '/((?:https?|rtmp):\/\/(?:\S*?\.\S*?)(?:[\s)\[\]{};"\'<]?(.mkv)|\.\s|$))/'];
    $replace = ['', '', ''];
    $result = preg_replace($find, $replace, $m3ufile);
    $re         = '/((?:https?|rtmp):\/\/(?:\S*?\.\S*?)(?:[\s)\[\]{};"\'<]|\.\s|$))/';
    $attributes = '/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+?)="([^"]*)"/';
    preg_match_all($re, $result, $matches);
    $items = array();
    foreach ($matches[0] as $list) {
        preg_match($re, $list, $matchList);
        $mediaURL = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/", "", $matchList[3]);
        $mediaURL = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $mediaURL);
        $channelName = $matchList[2];
        $stringUrl = $mediaURL;
        $newdata  = array(
            'stringName' => $matchList[2],
            'listURL' => $url,
            'stringUrl' => $mediaURL,
            'listId' => ':listId'
        );
        preg_match_all($attributes, $list, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            $newdata[$match[1]] = $match[2];
        }
        $items[] = $newdata;
        echo 'Insert: (' . $matchList[2] . ' - ' . $mediaURL . ' - ' . $url . ')' . "\r\n";
        $mylink = new Article;
        $mylink->storeFormValues2($_POST);
        $mylink->insertstringsFuncClass();
    }
}
insertStrings();
```

all i got for inserted values is null

Comment: Just to be accurate, in SQL `null` is not a value, it's just null.

Comment: thanks for clarification im a beginner in php/mysql im just trying to understand

Comment: if nulls are inserted then you are inserting nulls. Which means the problem is not with pdo/mysql but with your PHP code. make sure all values are set

Comment: $listId = $conn->lastInsertId(); is probably the source of error

Comment: i tried multiple methods with liastinsertid() but no success this is the only working way

Comment: And making a new connection in each method will cause you probelms eventually as well

Comment: how to get this id and re insert it in the second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution i just work with `global` i put it in file.php in the two function and tadaaa it worked

`global $listId;`
but i had to insert from this file not from the class .